# Bootstrap Daterangepicker loading on dynamic html notworking in firefox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, daterangepicker

I'm using daterangepicker after updating html content with ajax.
The script is as below,

```
$('.ordtpick').daterangepicker({
    "minDate": "01/01/2014",
    "maxDate": "01/01/2020",
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "showDropdowns": true,
    "autoApply": true,
    "timePicker": true,
    "timePickerIncrement": 5,
    "format": 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A'
});
```

This is working fine in chrome but On clicking the timepicker,am/pm, month, year dropdowns are not dropping (opening) in firefox

Comment: _after updating html content with ajax_ and how you are doing this?

Comment: Initialize the `daterangepicker` after updating html content through ajax.

Comment: Initialize the `daterangepicker` after updating html content through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is an issue with bootstrap's `modal` and datepicker's dropbox controls. I have Solved it by adding following line right after Initializing the datepicker code.

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Don't know what does the line mean but got it solved.